# SQL how count last entries for each id based on a criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

I have a non periodic art course.
Every day I add a new "present" entry to a table.

I would like to know what are the student that missed the last 2 days. Just the last 2 days.

> Important, each student choose a different weekday to have a class. and some of them 2 days per week.

I do have 2 tables, **Students** and **Presences**.

presents is a 3 column table : student_id, day, present.

I would to get a query highlighting all students that misses the last 2 days.

This would return a table with 3 column: Student_Id,Name and if misses the two last day, How can I get this result?

The table strucure is

- **Student**  id: int, name: varchar
- **Presence** student_id: int, day: date, present: boolean

An data example

```
presences                                   students
student_id  day           present           id   name  
---------------------------------           ------------
1           2016-01-01    0                 1    'Bob'
1           2016-01-10    1                 2    'Carol'
1           2016-01-20    0

2           2016-01-15    1
2           2016-01-27    0
2           2016-01-21    0
```

In this case Bob misses just the last day, and Carol misses last 2 days. the expected result would be:

```
student_id  name   misses_two_last_days 
----------------------------------------
1           Bob     FALSE
2           Carol   TRUE
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the table structure along with dummy data and the expected result. Not sure how you got to this query, but it seems awkward.

Comment: first, davejal is right you should give use the table structure otherwise we won't know how you get that error. second, did you try only exc the subquery part? is there also a error?

Comment: What constitutes the `last 2 days`?  Is it the same for every student?  Or are you trying to check if the last 2 days the student came were they there.  Slightly different, but result in very different answers...

Comment: Question edited with more details and table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of problems with your query.  Try rewriting it to use `joins`.  You also have to define the last 2 days.  I've attempted to do that with a `subquery` below.  Then you need to use `aggregation` to see if the student missed both days.  Here's something that should be close:

```
select s.id, s.name
from students s
   inner join presences p on s.id = p.student_id and p.present = false
   inner join (select distinct day 
               from presences 
               order by day desc 
               limit 2) t on p.day = t.day
group by s.id, s.name
having count(p.day) = 2
```

---

Rereading your question, if you want to return all students and not just those that have missed the last 2 days, you need to use `outer joins` instead and remove the `having` clause and replace with a `case` statement:

```
select s.id, s.name, 
    case when count(p.day) = 2 then 'missed' else '' end as Missed
from students s
   left join presences p on s.id = p.student_id and p.present = false
   left join (select distinct day 
               from presences 
               order by day desc 
               limit 2) t on p.day = t.day
group by s.id, s.name
```

Comment: It seems that "having count(p.day) = 2" part is not needed. there is any particular reason to have it added?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with one subuqery. Please check if it meets your requirement.

```
SELECT 
    s.id, 
    s.name,
    ( SELECT SUM(p.present = false)
      FROM p
      WHERE p.student_id = s.id 
      ORDER BY p.day DESC
      LIMIT 2 ) AS misses_two_last_days
FROM s;
```

Answer (score 0):

now since you just give so little information, what i can tell you is what's wrong with your subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
(SELECT p.student_id 
       FROM p WHERE p.student_id = s.id  ORDER BY p.day DESC LIMIT 2) AS subquery
WHERE p.present = false
```

let's check this, you rename the table as **subquery** and yet your where is still using **p.present** that's why you get the error. database can't get what is **p**. and your query is kind of miserable, if you can describe it clear, i'll try to help you get it work

Answer (score -1):

you have to define the aliases for the tables that you are using in the query.

For example:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, p.day FROM 
Students s, Presences p 
WHERE s.id = p.student_id
```

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an aswer

Comment: I can understand and I will try not to repeat the same mistake in the future.